# QGIS as OGC Data Server only returns white box

Tags: wms, qgis-server, debian, ows

I just setup my QGIS Server as a OGC Data Server following: [Installation on Debian-based systems](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#installation-on-debian-based-systems).

When I try to access it and retrieve my QGIS project using the following link http://localhost:8080/qgisserver?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&MAP=/projects/example/world3.qgs&LAYERS=countries&WIDTH=400&HEIGHT=200&CRS=EPSG:4326, I just receive a 400x200 white box. Any idea what could cause this?

This log was created for the request: https://pastebin.com/h9sTycg2

A `GetCapabilities` request to the following link

http://localhost:8080/qgisserver?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&MAP=/projects/example/world3.qgs

produces the following output: https://pastebin.com/iqGDFhxU

I tried to setup the server 3 times now following the documentation and I always end up with the QGIS server only returning white boxes instead of the map.

Comment: The GetMap request is missing required parameters

Answer (score 1):

The GetCapabilities response seems to be valid, and you get a response to the request so the WMS service appears to be working as expected.

The GetMap request you've made (or reported in the question) is invalid as it's missing required parameters, I'm surprised you get any image response as the default error is XML unless you specify differently using the `EXCEPTIONS` parameter.

You are missing styles (either like `styles&` or `styles=default&` or specified in and SLD parameter...), version (I assume `version=1.3.0&` as you have CRS), bbox (min lat, min lon, max lat, max long for EPSG:4326), output format (like `format=image/png&`).

Assuming/once you have a correct request then a white image response (with no error text) might not mean you have a bad response, just your bounding box describes an area of no data.

Rather than hand cranking GetMap requests to test a service, why not instead load the WMS into QGIS desktop, specifying the endpoint for the GetCapabilities request in this case `http://localhost:8080/qgisserver?MAP=/projects/example/world3.qgs&` then zoom to extent.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem and a solution is very easy but doesn't mention on official docs. You need to specify bbox parameter on url.

For the mentioned world.qgs project try:

```
BBOX=-25345974.386137474%2C16185170.55818786%2C34789346.44239271%2C23844254.527065746
```